# Difference between words like "mensonger" and "mensongère"

Tags: choix-de-mot

I've been studying some French vocab and I noticed a few vocab words such as mensonger and passager have two forms: one as a verb, and the other with an "-ère" ending. When I translate both words next to each other, they are shown as the same word. Is there any difference in meaning or just or just function?

Comment: There is no such verb as *mensonger*, the verb is *mentir* and *passager* as a verb is obsolete.

Comment: The fact that a word ends with *er* does not mean in anyway it is a verb. Both *passager* and *mensonger* are adjectives (*passager* can also be a noun), [this will help you](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-i/french-i-adjectives/changing-masculine-to-singular-feminine) to get rules about the feminine of adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

If you started to study french, I am sure that you realized that there is a concept of grammatical gender.

> Le/la
>   Un/une
>   Un lapin
>   Une lapine
>   Un lapin mensonger!
>   Une lapine mensongère!

Comment: Oh, it's just an irregular form of grammatical gender. I probably should have thought of that considering I've been studying French for three years.... Anyhow, thank you.

Comment: @MorellaAlmånd It's not actually irregular... The feminine form of words ending in -er usually is -ère, e.g. laitier/laitière, messager/messagère, douanier/douanière, conseiller/conseillère, etc.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true. I just meant as opposed to just adding an, "e" to the end, but I know that many words don't follow that pattern directly. I guess that isn't really considered irregular.

Comment: You also simply add an "e", but you have to also add an accent to keep correct pronunciation. That's often how it works in French : we change something according to a rule, and then we add accents (or letters) so that the spelling is consistent to the pronunciation. Ex: *ambigu* takes an "e" when it's feminine, making *ambigue*, but that would be said "*ambig*" so we have to add an accent, a *tréma* here, making: *ambigüe*

Comment: @TeleportingGoat In the rectified orthography. Traditionally, it's *ambiguë*.

Comment: @Kareen Yes, I didn't want to confuse even more. The rectified orthography is more logical so easier for a learner. Here they moved the ¨ to the letter that is actually said differently, it changes the *u* not the *e*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I agree, but it's also less commonly taught, I think, and definitely less commonly used in general, so people are more likely to come across the traditional spelling. Most dictionaries also don't mention it. Just thought I'd point it out!